# How to see all available properties of Get-PnPListItem

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-online

I am getting a bit confused with getting all properties of Get-PnPListItem command
If I do
`$list = (Get-PnPListItem -List $folder  -PageSize 500 -Connection $gcon  ).FieldValues`
and then
`foreach($f in $list){ $f  |  Get-member }` 
it only shows few properties, like "Compare", "Count" etc, but if I start typing  `f.` in ISE it suggests a lot of properties, like "FileLeafRef", "File_x0020_Type" and much more.
So the question is - how do I get the list of all available properties of Get-PnPListItem output?
Thanks

Comment: You could try `$f | Format-List *` instead of `Get-member`

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me: `$list[0].FieldValues.Keys`

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
$Items = (Get-PnPListItem -List $folder -Fields $global:FieldsList -Connection $gcon).FieldValues    
foreach($Item in $Items)
{
    Write-Host $Item.Title
}
```